# Как изменить путь к БД в C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, c++-cli

Работаю над проектом в Visual Studio C#. В проекте есть несколько форм и в каждом из них я использую oledbconnection и oledbadapter для подключения БД. Хотел бы спросить: 
1) Можно ли в проекте указать один путь к БД и в каждой форме не использовать oledbconnection?
2) Как в текущем проекте, изменить путь к БД во всех формах (oledbconnection)?

Comment: В C++ никаких "форм" нет, вы похоже работаете с C++ CLI.

Comment: Да, Точно. Извините, я в этом деле новичок, поэтому и спрашиваю...

Comment: По C++ CLI мало вопросов и ответов, похоже мало кто на нем работает. Попробуйте спросить у тех, кто пишет на шарпе, там же вроде тот же самый дотнет, наверняка что-то об этом знают.

Comment: Уберите из заголовка и вопроса упоминание С++ и добавьте метку.

Answer (score 0):

> Можно ли в проекте указать один путь к БД и в каждой форме не использовать oledbconnection

Нет.

> Как в текущем проекте, изменить путь к БД во всех формах (oledbconnection)

Скорее всего, вам нужно приписать строку подключения в app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>  
<configuration>   
    <connectionStrings>  
      <add name="MyDbConnectionString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\myFolder\MyDB.mdb;" />  
    </connectionStrings>  
</configuration>
```

И добавить в проект ссылку на System.Configuration.dll. После этого вы можете в любой форме создавать соединения так:

```
var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDbConnectionString"].ConnectionString;  
using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString)) 
{
    //...
}
```